# Blue Plane vs Pink Plane - existing philosophical category?

Tags: ontology

In The [Act of Creation (Arkana) 1964, Arkana Reissue Edition, Paperback, ISBN 0140191917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140191917)  by  Arthur Koestler he sets up a Contrast between the **Pink Plane** and the **Blue Plane**.

In it he describes the incremental improvement plane (which called the "pink" plane) and the paradigm shift (or "blue") plane.

The [following quote](http://www.memestreams.net/thread/bid12692/) comes from the book:

> Let us explore the meaning of the pink plane. It represents a more black and white way of portraying the universe. It declares that things are either right or wrong, they work or fail; it applauds discrete knowledge over reasoning and derivation of concepts. It is a plane of thought where math and science are memorized facts and equations.
>
> The blue plane, on the other hand, can be described as perpendicular to the pink plane. The two planes might coincide on a line, where the same rules apply in the physical universe, and hence results can be the same, however the means is completely different. In this plane of thought, visualization of concepts and creativity can be used to accomplish what is accomplished in the pink plane by trite memorization.

**My question is - does this contrast between incrementalism and radical change have more fundamental categories in philosophy? Is there some root idea explains this dichotomy?**

We appear to see echos of this contrast in Accounting, when it comes to Capital Expenditure and Operational Expenditure. We see it in Change Management, when we look at Iterative changes vs Big Bang changes.